# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type ..." when entity class and Spring data repository in same package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I've got a pretty weird behaviour in my simple Spring Application. I am not able to have a JPA Entity and a Spring Data Repository in the same package.

I would like to build a very simple web application in which I manage some Users. So I started from scratch and created the following project structure:

```
src
 |
 +-- main
    |  
    +-- de.my.mainpackage
      |    
      +-- client
      |  |
      |  +-- ClientApp.java
      |
      +-- core
        |
        +-- user
           |
           +-- User.java
           |
           +-- UserRepository.java
```

Code of User.java:

```
package de.my.mainpackage.core.user;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
}
```

Code of UserRepository.java:

```
package de.my.mainpackage.core.user;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

Code of ClientApp.java:

```
package de.my.mainpackage.client;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import de.my.mainpackage.core.user.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("de.my.mainpackage.core.user")
public class ClientApp {

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(ClientApp.class, args);
        ClientApp clientApp = (ClientApp)applicationContext.getBean("clientApp");

        System.out.println("userRepository is = " + clientApp.userRepository);
    }
}
```

So my idea was to separate the model and the repository into an own directory core.user while the main application logic should stay in the client subfolder. But when I run my Spring Application with this configuration, I get the following Error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=61131 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=61132:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Artur\IdeaProjects\repositoryissue\target\classes;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.11\logback-classic-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.11\logback-core-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jdbc\8.5.23\tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\8.5.23\tomcat-juli-8.5.23.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.0.12.Final\hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.21.0-GA\javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.0.Final\jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.0.12.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\1.11.9.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\1.13.9.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.25\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.16.18\lombok-1.16.18.jar;C:\Users\Artur\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.44\mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar" de.my.mainpackage.client.ClientApp

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2017-12-30 19:56:07.068  INFO 11140 --- [           main] de.my.mainpackage.client.ClientApp       : Starting ClientApp on WinBook with PID 11140 (C:\Users\Artur\IdeaProjects\repositoryissue\target\classes started by Artur in C:\Users\Artur\IdeaProjects\repositoryissue)
2017-12-30 19:56:07.068  INFO 11140 --- [           main] de.my.mainpackage.client.ClientApp       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-30 19:56:07.177  INFO 11140 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@b7f23d9: startup date [Sat Dec 30 19:56:07 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-30 19:56:08.332  INFO 11140 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-30 19:56:08.348  INFO 11140 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-12-30 19:56:08.457  INFO 11140 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-12-30 19:56:08.457  INFO 11140 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-12-30 19:56:08.457  INFO 11140 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-12-30 19:56:08.488  INFO 11140 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-12-30 19:56:08.551  INFO 11140 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-12-30 19:56:08.660  INFO 11140 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2017-12-30 19:56:08.676  INFO 11140 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-30 19:56:08.770  WARN 11140 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientApp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class de.my.mainpackage.core.user.User
2017-12-30 19:56:08.770  INFO 11140 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-30 19:56:08.785  INFO 11140 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-30 19:56:08.809 ERROR 11140 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientApp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class de.my.mainpackage.core.user.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at de.my.mainpackage.client.ClientApp.main(ClientApp.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class de.my.mainpackage.core.user.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class de.my.mainpackage.core.user.User
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:173) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

In order to make the `UserRepository` available to `ClientApp` I added the `@EnableJpaRepositories("de.my.mainpackage.core.user")`. Now the weird thing:

When I move the User.java up to the client subpackage, it works fine. 
Like this:

```
 src
     |
     +-- main
        |  
        +-- de.my.mainpackage
          |    
          +-- client
          |  |
          |  +-- ClientApp.java
          |  |
          |  +-- User.java
          |
          +-- core
            |
            +-- user
               |               
               |
               +-- UserRepository.java
```

Output:

```
...
2017-12-30 20:05:56.032  INFO 12704 --- [           main] de.my.mainpackage.client.ClientApp       : Started ClientApp in 2.799 seconds (JVM running for 3.815)
userRepository is = org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@736048ed
2017-12-30 20:05:56.048  INFO 12704 --- [       Thread-9] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@b7f23d9: startup date [Sat Dec 30 20:05:53 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-30 20:05:56.048  INFO 12704 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-12-30 20:05:56.048  INFO 12704 --- [       Thread-9] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, I spent a lot of time and tried to figure out what I am doing wrong... No Idea.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-entity-classes: *By default all packages below your main configuration class (the one annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication`) will be searched [...] You can customize entity scanning locations using the `@EntityScan` annotation.*

Answer (score 9):

Thanks @JB Nizet:

I thought, that by setting **@EnableJpaRepositories** and **@ComponentScan** with the right packages, that would be enough. I did not know, that for Entities you need also **@EntityScan**. Thanks a lot for that hint!

Comment: This helped me a day's work! Thanks a lot @JB Nizet